# Trying to install Tensorflow with Anaconda-navigator but can not find the package in the navigator

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install Tensorflow with Anaconda-navigator but can not find the package in the navigator.

[image: tesnorflow not displayed in not installed section]

I haven't installed any of the extra packages like keras, openCV etc. So they must display in the above section.

**I also tried searching for TensorFlow in the all section**

[image]

Also tried the same with base(root) environment.
Please help.
**Even tried installing tensorflow using cmd prompt. That throws an error**
therefore I want to install it using the navigator only.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow isn't in the "defaults" anaconda channel. It is on conda-forge instead. In order to add conda-forge to your channels:

1. Click on "channels" (left of where you searched for tensorflow)
2. Click on "add"
3. Paste this URL in: https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/
4. Press enter
5. Press "Update channels"
6. Now search again, and it should be there!

[conda-forge added to channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g29c.png)

Source: https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html

Comment: I followed the steps you told. But I still can't see any of the packages there. Any idea?

Comment: Could you send the error you get when trying to install it from the cmd, @AlishaMaini

Comment: You don't have to paste the url; instead you can add by writing "conda-forge". After follow the steps as usual, It works.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the steps described above (with the version @aysebilgegunduz mentioned), I also had to "Update index..." after adding "conda-forge" to the environment's channels. Afterwards, I found the desired package.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow isn't in the "defaults" anaconda channel. It is on conda-forge instead. In order to add conda-forge to your channels:

Click on "channels" (left of where you searched for tensorflow)

Click on "add"

Paste this URL in: https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/

Press enter

Press "Update channels"

Now search again, and it should be there!